# Error when entering Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm running Excel 2013 in Win 8.1 Pro 64bits edition and every time I try to open a Excel file it gives me "**There was a problem sending the command to the program**" and the file doesn't open.

When Excel instance is open the  file opens fine.

I try solutions found in [a Microsoft Community page](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-excel/getting-the-error-there-was-a-problem-sending-the/b8e4bfab-d1f6-49e2-8e8d-068dfe3b8655?msgId=33cfb076-e6ea-4963-ba29-b40bf977693a) but it didn't work:

- *Clear the Ignore other applications that use Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE)* - it was not checked in the first place
- *Excel (.exe) 
  Properties > Compatibility > uncheck all the boxes* - there was no
  boxes checked

Comment: Do you have any previous versions of Office installed? Do you have the Excel Viewer Installed?

Comment: @xxl3ww No, I haven't

Comment: Do you have any addons installed? The reason I asked is because I was having this problem. When I disabled all the addons, the problem cleared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

Under Excel Options > Advanced > Display

Check the option "**Disable hardware graphics accelaration**".

It clear my entering problem and problems when usign Excel!